# Equivalent of tf.identity with control dependency for an operation node

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am writing a wrapper class that takes a generic graph with a special member "train_op" to manage the training, saving, and housekeeping of my model.

I wanted to cleanly keep track of the lifetime number of training steps like so:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([ step_add_one ]):
    self.train_op=tf.identity(self.training_graph.train_op )
```

> raise TypeError('Expected binary or unicode string, got %r' 
>       e, is_training=True, inputs=None)

I think the rub here is that train_op is the return of tf.Optimizer.minimize(), so it is not a tensor per se, but an operation.

An obvious workaround would be to call tf.identity on the training_graph.loss, but I lose a bit of abstraction because I have to then handle the learning rate etc externally. Moreover, I feel like I'm missing something.

How can I best remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.group()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#group), which will work with operations **and** tensors.

For instance:

```
x = tf.Variable(1.)
loss = tf.square(x)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

step = tf.Variable(0)
step_add_one = step.assign_add(1)

with tf.control_dependencies([step_add_one]):
    train_op_2 = tf.group(train_op)
```

Now when you run `train_op_2`, the value of `step` will be incremented.

---

However, the best way to go (if you can modify the graph that created the graph) is to add a parameter `global_step` to the `minimize` function:

```py
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=step)
```

Comment: I usually feed step to minimize directly, but why is that "better" in this case?; Also, thanks for the expedient help

Comment: It's not better in computation, it's just easier than using a control dependency. It's "better" in the sense "best practice".